# Get count of duplicated values per category/group in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a df1 like this:

```
Type     Name     Identifier     Number     Amount
 A        xx          0001         12        0.89
          xx          0001         56        0.78
          zz          0002         33        0.56
          yy          0020         44        0.45
          yy          0020         67        0.45
 B        ww          0300         12        0.34
          ww          0300         54        0.1
          kk          0900         43        0.2
```

I want to get the count of the duplicated identifier per type such that the resulting dataframe now looks like

```
 Type     Count_Dups      Ave. Amount  
  A         2                2.345  
  B         1                0.44
```

where ave. amount is the sum of all duplicated values / count of duplicated values. (example: A = (0.89+0.78+0.45+0.45)/2)

should I use a for loop? is groupby enough?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "count of the duplicated identifier", because in your example there are always the same number of different identifiers duplicated as there are rows which are duplicates of a previous row.  E.g. does [1, 2, 3, 3, 3] have a duplicate count of 1 or 2?

Comment: (0.89+0.78+0.45+0.45)/2 is not 2.345.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: @DSM I want  to get the count of the duplicated values per group. In group A there are 2 duplicates(0001 and 0002) whereas in group B there is 1 identifier that is duplicated(0300).

Comment: @HarvIpan I've tried using a for loop but doesn't show the output I want.

Comment: @DYZ so sorry, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use this method.  Filter the dataframe down to the duplicates, then groupby with nunique and sum, lastly, divide the two columns.

```
df_out = df1[df1.duplicated(subset=['Type','Identifier'], keep=False)]\
             .groupby('Type')['Identifier','Amount']\
             .agg({'Identifier':'nunique','Amount':'sum'})\
             .rename(columns={'Identifier':'Count_Dups'})

df_out['Ave. Amount'] = df_out['Amount']  / df_out['Count_Dups']

print(df_out.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  Type  Count_Dups  Amount  Ave. Amount
0    A           2    2.57        1.285
1    B           1    0.44        0.440
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify the duplicates, group the rows by their types and identifiers:

```
dups = df.groupby(['Type', 'Identifier'])['Amount']\
         .agg(['size', 'sum']).reset_index()
#  Type  Identifier  size   sum
#0    A           1     2  1.67
#1    A           2     1  0.56
#2    A          20     2  0.90
#3    B         300     2  0.44
#4    B         900     1  0.20
```

Select the lines that occur more than once:

```
dups = dups[dups['size'] > 1]
```

Count their partials sums:

```
dups_stats = dups.groupby('Type')['sum']\
                 .agg(['size','sum'])
#      size   sum
#Type            
#A        2  2.57
#B        1  0.44
```

Finally, divide the sums by the counts to get the averages:

```
dups_stats['sum'] /= dups_stats['size']
#      size    sum
#Type             
#A        2  1.285
#B        1  0.440
```